# Do we need a canonical "I have forgotten my Google username and/or Password" answer?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

From [time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/what-do-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-gmail-password) to [time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/forgotten-my-old-google-username-and-password) there are questions from people who have forgotten their Google username, password or both.

It is certainly OK to just add a [comment with a link to the Account Recovery Form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/forgotten-my-old-google-username-and-password), but would it be better if we had a community wiki question which mentions the form, and possibly could be expanded to include other options?

Then, all Google account recovery questions could be marked as duplicates of this one.

Comment: I've actually been thinking of doing this since a while.

Comment: I [asked something similar](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/my-insert-email-web-app-here-account-has-been-hacked111-halp111one) but it never got any traction.

Comment: In a related vein, I've gone ahead and put together a Q/A for what one should do _before_ one loses access to one's account: [How do I protect my Google/Gmail account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have gone ahead and [started something](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-password-or-username/52707#52707).

Consider this very much a work in progress, and please add/edit in any details or other information you may have.

Or feel free to comment here.

Comment: Very nicely done.